# Relocation in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, bare-metal

I have a boot-up code for a bare-metal ARM written in assembly and I'm trying to understand how it works. The binary is written in some external Flash, and is copying parts of itself in RAM at boot-up. I still didn't exactly get the concept of relocation in this context, even though I read this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29). The RAM is mapped to a low address window, and the flash in a high address window. Can someone explain to me why we test the value of the link register here?

```
/* Test if we are running from an address, we are not linked at */
       bl check_position
 check_position:
        mov     r0, lr                  
        ldr     r1, =check_position
        cmp     r0, r1                  /* ; don't relocate during debug */
        beq     relocated_entry
```

Comment: Thank you for the two excellent answers! I would accept both if I coud, since one explains the goal of the code (the JTAG program loader assumption is right) and the second how it works exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is the application runs from ram, and when debugging the application this author is perhaps using some sort of bootloader and or jtag to load the test app directly into ram, thus no reason to copy and run (which could cause a crash).

Another reason you would do something like this is to avoid an infinite loop.  If for example you want to boot from flash (have to usually) but execute from ram, the simplest way to do that is to just copy the whole flash or whole some chunk of flash to ram and just branch to the start of ram.  Which when you do that means you hit the "copy the app to ram and branch" loop again, to avoid it the second time (which might crash you), you have some sort of am I running this loop from flash or not test.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain to me why we test the value of the link register here?

The `bl check_position` will place the value of `PC+4` in the link register and transfer control to the `check_position` also PC relative.<sup>[bl at ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihfddaf.html)</sup>  So far everything is `PC` relative.

The `ldr r1,=check_position` gets a value from the **literal pool**.<sup>Ref1</sup>  The actual code looks like,

```
  ldr r1,[pc, #offset]
...
  offset:
    .long check_position   # absolute address from assemble/link.
```

So the `R0` contains a PC relative version and the `R1` contains the absolute assembled version.  Here, they are compared.  You could also use arithmetic to calculate the difference and then *branch* to it if non-zero; or possibly copy the code to it's absolute destination.<sup>Ref2</sup>  If the code is *running* at the *linked* address, then `R0` and `R1` are the same.  This is some `pseudo code` for `bl`.

```
 mov lr,pc               ; pc is actually two instruction ahead.
 add pc,pc,#branch_offset-8
```

The key is that `BL` does everything based on the `PC` including the update of `lr`.  Instead of using this *trick*, we could use `mov R0,PC`, except the `PC` is 8 bytes ahead.  Another alternative would be to use `adr R0,check_position`, which would get the assembler to do all the address math for us.

```
 /* Test if we are running from an address, we are not linked at */
 check_position:
    adr    r0, check_position
    ldr    r1, =check_position
    cmp    r0, r1                  /* ; don't relocate during debug */
    beq    relocated_entry
```

An ARMv6 version might look like this,

```
 /* Test if we are running from an address, we are not linked at */
 check_position:
    adr    r0, check_position
    movw   r1, #:lower16:check_position
    movt   r1, #:upper16:check_position
    cmp    r0, r1                  /* ; don't relocate during debug */
    beq    relocated_entry
```

In both cases, the code is more straight forward, smaller by one word and doesn't over write the `lr` register, so it could be used for other purposes.

**Ref1:** See [Arm op-codes](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html) and [.ltorg](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.htm) in gnu-assembler manual 
**Ref2:** This is exactly what the Linux `head.S` is doing for the ARM.

**Edit:** I checked the ARM ARM and the PC is apparently the current instruction `+8`, which goes to show why the code was like this.  I think the `adr` version is more direct and readable, but the `adr` pseudo-op is not used as often so people may not be familiar with it.