# Getting an label address to a register on ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm

How do I write an instruction which will have the address a label is referencing put into a register?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are four ways, three are documented at [Sourceware's Gnu Assembler manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html).  I guess the label is something like,

```
 target:
     .long 0xfeadbeef
```

1. `adr r0,target`  - pc-relative
2. `adrl r0,target` -  pc-relative
3. `ldr   r0,=target` - absolute
4. `sub   r0,pc,#(.+8-target)` - learning only...

The first two are very similar and generate `sub r0,pc,#offset`.  The 3<sup>rd</sup> puts a long in a *literal pool* and loads this via `ldr r0,[pc,#offset2]` or it may use a `mov` if the assembler finds it can (usually an aligned label, like at *0x8000*).

The last version (4) is to manually calculated it.  This is what the `adr` and `adrl` versions will windup translating to.  It is not recommended, but is just to show how the `.` operator (current address), the `pc` and the `label` along with the convention that the ARM PC is eight ahead of the current executing instruction combine.  If it looks confusing, this is why we have `adr`.

The difference between `adr` and `adrl` comes from immediate operands.  They are *8bits* rotated by a multiple of two.  So if the address is far, you may need to perform two instructions, which will usually be faster than the 3<sup>rd</sup> `ldr` variant which get a full 32-bits via the *data cache* or *memory*.

See also: [Relocation in assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671717/relocation-in-assembly%29)

---

Thumb2 adds the combination `movw` and `movt`, which is absolute addressing.  For example,

```
label:
 ; data
...
movw    r0, :lower16:label - .
movt    r0, :upper16:label - .
```

This will put the offset in `r0`.  It is not as useful for PC relative but  useful for absolutes or direct loads of constants.

---

Ironically, the `ldr r0,=target` is actually using the `adr` variation to do a PC-relative load.  Here is the pseudo-code for the variant.

```
ldr r0, [pc, target_target]  ; get literal pool value.
 ...
target_target:               ; the literal pool
.long target                 ; an inserted absolute address
target:
.long 0xfeadbeef
```

The 'target_target' is handled automatically by the assembler and is referred to as the literal pool and can be controlled with the `.ltorg` statement.  Many projects will use the 'ldr rx,=xxxx' form.  This is possibly the best way to get a **constant** to a register and also works for a label.  Hopefully it is clear why `adr` is better for a label.

'pc-relative' is often useful for shared libraries and boot code where the executing address may not be constant. The pc-relative versions will also execute a little faster and the 'label' can be a jump table for faster dispatch where you want to do one of several things based on a value.

---

See: [ARM blog on constants](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture)

Comment: `movk`  (over `movw` and `movt`) can be used on ARM64; all other concepts are the same with registers named with an 'X' versus an 'R' for a 64bit value.

Comment: `target_target` and `target` might be in different or the same sections.  Depending, the assembler might not create some of the '.long' values.  But it is just to say that constants and labels (or any values not fitting in a standard `mov`) will be encoded as a PC-relative `ldr`.