# Writing data to absolute address

Tags: assembly, cortex-m, thumb

I'm currently playing around a bit with assembler on a Cortex-M3 microcontroller. I'm not sure if this is important, but here you go.

I need to write a value into to a certain address in memory. Here is what I tried:

```
LDR     R4, =__cs3_interrupt_vector_cortex_m
STR     R4, [=VTOR]
```

But it seems like I need to reference the VTOR address relative to the PC register. The question is if there is a way to not reference the address relativ and let this do automatically (so that it would basically look like my approach).

I'm using GNU Assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the destination address to a register.  I assume that `VTOR` is a memory address or 'C' pointer and `__cs3_interrupt_vector_cortex_m` is a constant.  Ie, you wish to write a 32bit constant to an address.  If this is the case then,

```
 ; Get value __cs3_interrupt_vector_cortex_m to r4
 ldr r4, =__cs3_interrupt_vector_cortex_m 
 ldr r5, =VTOR ; address 'VTOR' to r5.
 str r4, [r5]  ; write the constant to 'VTOR' address.
```

The ARM/Thumb/Thumb2 is a *load-store* architecture.  You can not use memory operands in the load and store instructions.  This simplifies the CPU design, but is different from M68K and x86 assembler.

The syntax `ldr rX, =val` is explained in the [Gnu assembler info pages](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html).  Generally it will convert to the following,

```
ldr   rX, [pc, #offset]
...
offset: .word val ; your constant is stored here.
```

The *pseudo-op `.ltorg`*  tells the assembler to dump the literal table; the *offset* portion of code above.  You can add an `.ltorg` anywhere between sub-routines, etc.

You can not use the syntax `str r4,[=VTOR]` as the *equals* syntax is only a short-cut for use with `ldr`.  For example,

```
ldr   rX,=7          ; is really 'mov rx,#7' in all modes.
ldr   rX,=0xff       ; is 'mov rx,#0xff' for ARM and '[pc,#offset]' for thumb.
ldr   rx,=0x12345678 ; will use the [pc, #offset] for all modes.
```

You can use the `ldr rX,=VTOR` syntax to get the address to a register.  It then takes another instruction like `str rY, [rX]` to actually write to that address.

Constants are encoded inside an instruction so the constant range is very limited especially in **thumb** mode.  I guess you are using **thumb2** which may have more range.

Comment: Perhaps also of interest.  [Label to address on ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm)  and [blog on ARM constants](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture).  `movw` and `movt` are also alternatives for new ARM CPUs (armv6+) in 32bit modes.