# Howto write PC relative adressing on arm asm?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm using GNU AS as assembler and I'm trying to write a position independent binary and I have some problems writing the PC relative address of an external symbols. Normaly a relative address is loaded with

```
adr r0, symbol
```

but that only works for symbols defined in the same section in the assembly file. The other method to load a symbol is

```
ldr r0, =symbol
```

which stores the absolute address of the symbol in a constant and loads it pc relative from there. So you get code like this:

```
  48:   e59f0008        ldr     r0, [pc, #8]    ; 58 <text+0xc>
  ...
  58:   00000008        .word   0x00200018
                        58: R_ARM_ABS32 symbol
```

But what I need is a **R_ARM_REL32** linker reference.

What I have come up with is this code:

```
tmp1:    ldr    r0, [pc, #tmp2 - tmp1 - 8]
         ldr    r0, [pc, r0]
tmp2:    .word  symbol - tmp1
```

This produces:

```
0000003c <tmp1>:
  3c:   e59f0000        ldr     r0, [pc]        ; 44 <tmp2>
  40:   e79f0000        ldr     r0, [pc, r0]

00000044 <tmp2>:
  44:   00000008        .word   0x00000008
                        44: R_ARM_REL32 symbol
```

I can nearly put that into a macro so it is reusesable for whatever symbol I need. Except I don't know how to tell the assembler that tmp2 needs to go to the constants block instead of ending up right there in the middle of the code.

But isn't there already some existing syntax or macro for that in GNU AS?

Comment: Did you try [`adrl`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html)?  This should allow larger references and you can use `-fwhole-program`.  I don't think you can do this in 'C' without some sort of relocation (like plt, glt, etc).  Typically, 'C' thinks you can do thing like access global variables, etc.  For the ARM ABI, *.text* and *.data* can be far apart and the compiler needs to support this. There is also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/placing-the-address-a-register-is-pointing-at-in-to-a-register).  That said, u-boot does this with a 'sb'.

Comment: boot.S:49: Error: symbol symbol is in a different section

Comment: A R_ARM_REL32 ends up being listed in the .dyn.rel section (with my linker flags). At start one has to determine the offset between where the code is and where it should be and then add that offset to all addresses listed in .dyn.rel to fix things. Section can be far apart, that is why an extra 32bit value is needed and immediates don't work.

Answer (score 1):

**ARMv8**

Note that in ARMv8, the PC cannot be treated as a regular register anymore as was the case for ARMv7.

There is however a special PC-relative encoding for ldr called "LDR (literal)" with syntax:

```
    ldr x0, pc_relative_ldr
    b 1f
pc_relative_ldr:
    .quad 0x123456789ABCDEF0
1:
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/d0ab0ac861e80cf6c556d27e2bf9345e3fc0459f/v8/pc.S#L30).

Trying to do an old "LDR (register)" syntax as in:

```
ldr x0, [pc]
```

fails with:

```
64-bit integer or SP register expected at operand 2 -- `ldr x0,[pc]'
```

For some reason, there is not such PC-relative encoding for str. I think you just have to use `adr` + "STR (register)" as in:

```
    adr x1, pc_relative_str
    ldr x0, pc_relative_ldr
    str x0, [x1]
    ldr x0, pc_relative_str
.data
pc_relative_str:
    .quad 0x0000000000000000
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/d0ab0ac861e80cf6c556d27e2bf9345e3fc0459f/v8/pc.S#L51).

where `adr` loads a PC-relative address into a register.

You might also be interested in ADRP if you need longer jumps, see: [What are the semantics of ADRP and ADRL instructions in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly/54042899#54042899)

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the word explicitly. How about something like:

```
  .text                                                                          
1:  ldr   r0, =symbol-1b                                                         
    ldr   r0, [pc, r0]
```

This gives something like:

```
[~] dev% ~/ellcc/bin/ecc-objdump -d test.o
test.o:     file format elf32-bigarm
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   e59f0000        ldr     r0, [pc]        ; 8 <.text+0x8>
   4:   e79f0000        ldr     r0, [pc, r0]compatable
   8:   00000008        .word   0x00000008
```

with the right reloc:

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:                                                  
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000008 R_ARM_REL32       symbol
```

The relocated word will be placed somewhere after your code.

Caveat: I assembled this using clang's integrated assembler. I assume GNU as will handle the same thing since they try to be bug for bug compatible.

[Edit]
Unfortunately, as Jester mentions in the comments, this doesn't work with GNU as. I don't think I've ever seen an example where clang's integrated assembler did something that the GNU assembler couldn't handle before.

Comment: Unfortunately GNU `as` doesn't like it, it complains that it isn't a constant. My version is 2.18.50. I wanted to suggest this too...

Comment: @Jester: You're right. I just tried it with my 2.25 GNU assembler.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. Surprised me too that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Opened a bug about this for binutils: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18009

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is `movw` + `movt` an address into a register and then `ldr` relative to the PC.  The challenge is that the address you're loading need to be pre-corrected for PC relative access.  You can accomplish this by doing some pointer math in the constant passed to the `mov` instructions by subtracting the address of the `ldr` instruction from the absolute address of the symbol you're loading (plus a PC correction factor).

Since I don't have an assembler in front of me, actual implementation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: So, without the correcting terms something like this?
`tmp3: movw r0, #((symbol - tmp3) & 0xFFFF); movt r0, #((symbol - tmp3) >> 16)`. That gives: `boot.S:49: Error: constant expression expected -- 'movw r0,#((symbol-tmp3)&0xFFFF)'` and `boot.S:50: Error: constant expression expected -- 'movt r0,#((symbol-tmp3)>>16)'`  The "symbol" is not a constant since it will only be determined later by the linker. That limits the amount of math you can do with it.