# What is the purpose of ADR instructions in ARM?

Tags: linker, arm, arm64, bare-metal

I know that both `adr` and `ldr` pseudo instructions loads addr of a label. The difference between them is that `ldr` is absolute but `adr` is PC-relative.

**But when should I use which?**

I always use `ldr` to get the address when writing a bare-metal assembly progress. Can you give an explanation and example of using the `adr` instruction? Is it related to PIC(Position-Independent-Code)?

Comment: Another: [adrp and adrl in ARM Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`adr` generates a PC-relative address. It takes the address of the instruction itself and adds a signed offset that is encoded in the instruction to it.

The `ldr` pseudo-instruction (that is, `ldr x0, =label`) loads a pre-generated absolute address from a PC-relative position. At compile time, the absolute address of `label` is generated and embedded somewhere in the binary, and the (actual PC-relative) `ldr` instruction then loads that value from that place.

If we take a sample program (`_main` because I'm on macOS):

```
.globl _main
.p2align 2
_main:
    adr x1, label
    ldr x2, =label
    mov w0, 0
    ret

label:
    mov w0, 0x1234
    ret
```

Compiling this and looking at it in a disassembler yields:

```
;-- _main:
0x100003f98      81000010       adr x1, sym.func.100003fa8
0x100003f9c      a2000058       ldr x2, 0x100003fb0
0x100003fa0      00008052       mov w0, 0
0x100003fa4      c0035fd6       ret
;-- func.100003fa8:
0x100003fa8      80468252       mov w0, 0x1234
0x100003fac      c0035fd6       ret
0x100003fb0      a83f0000       invalid
0x100003fb4      01000000       invalid
```

Thus, the above program is equivalent to:

```
.globl _main
.p2align 2
_main:
    adr x1, label
    ldr x2, addressof_label
    mov w0, 0
    ret

label:
    mov w0, 0x1234
    ret

.p2align 3
addressof_label:
    .8byte label
```

This adds one level of indirection, and means that in an environment with ASLR, the dynamic linker must add the ASLR slide to `addressof_label`.