# Getting an label address to a register on THUMB assembly - Armv5

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, reverse-engineering, thumb

I am trying to get the the address of a label in thumb assembly and I am having some trouble.

I already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm) but that cannot help me and I will explain why.

I am writing an simple program with Thumb assembly ( unfortunately I cannot use Thumb2 ).

Let's consider this code:

> ```
>  .arch armv5te
>  .syntax unified
>  .text     
>
>  .thumb
>  .thumb_func
>  thumbnow:
>  0x0       PUSH {LR}
>  0x2       LDR R0, =loadValues
>  0x4       POP {PC}
>  .align
>  loadValues:
>  0x8        .word 0xdeadbee1
>  0xC        .word 0xdeadbee2
>  0x10       .word 0xdeadbee3
> ```

I am using the arm-linux-gnueabi toolchain to assemble that.

My microcontroller doesn't have an MMU so the memory address are static, no virtual pages etc.

The thing that I am trying to do is to make R0 having the value of 0x8 here so that then I can access the three words like this:

> ```
> LDR R1, [R0]
> LDR R2, [R0,#4]
> LDR R3, [R0,#8]
> ```

This is not possible with LDR though because the value in the word is not possible to fit in a MOV command. The documentation of the assembler states that if the value cannot fit in a MOV command then it will put the value in a literal pool.

So my question is, is it possible in Thumb assembly to get the actual address of the label if the content of the address cannot fit in a MOV command?

Comment: yes you let the tool put it a nearby pool and it gets it there.  gnu assembler will convert the ldr to a pc relative load.  did it not do that for you?

Comment: It does work with the literal pool but my question ( out of curiosity  mainly ) was if it's possible to actually get the address of the actual data and not the address to the literal pool instance.

Comment: as with any immediate in a fixed length instruction set you are limited as to how many significant bits.  arm, mips, risc-v, etc.   thumb and the 16 bit mips (and the 16 bit risc-v) instructions limit you further, so in general no.  it wont work for all cases.  The other problem with that desire is that the address is determined link time not during assembly, so arguably they could code for a pc-relative load, and then abandon that constant and at link time make it a pc relative add.  but didnt and perhaps that is a language thing (each assembly language for a target is specific to the tool)

Comment: if you use ldr on gnu assembler for arm it will if it can make it a mov if it knows the value at that time and it fits.  one would hope it would switch the ldr to an equivalent of the adr pseudo instruction as well, but didnt.  an experiment would be to use adr with a immediate that wont fit and see if the assembler fails, or turns it into an ldr plus add or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this

```
.thumb

    ldr r0,=hello
    adr r0,hello

nop
nop
nop
nop
hello:
    .word 0,1,2,3
```

gives this unlinked

```
00000000 <hello-0xc>:
   0:   4806        ldr r0, [pc, #24]   ; (1c <hello+0x10>)
   2:   a002        add r0, pc, #8  ; (adr r0, c <hello>)
   4:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   6:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   8:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

0000000c <hello>:
   c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
  10:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
  14:   00000002    andeq   r0, r0, r2
  18:   00000003    andeq   r0, r0, r3
  1c:   0000000c    andeq   r0, r0, r12
```

linked

```
00001000 <hello-0xc>:
    1000:   4806        ldr r0, [pc, #24]   ; (101c <hello+0x10>)
    1002:   a002        add r0, pc, #8  ; (adr r0, 100c <hello>)
    1004:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    1006:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    1008:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    100a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

0000100c <hello>:
    100c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    1010:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
    1014:   00000002    andeq   r0, r0, r2
    1018:   00000003    andeq   r0, r0, r3
    101c:   0000100c    andeq   r1, r0, r12
```

both ways r0 will return the address to the start of data from which you can then offset into that data from the caller or wherever.

### Edit

```
.thumb
adr r0,hello
nop
nop
nop

 arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:2: Error: address calculation needs a strongly defined nearby symbol
```

So the tool won't turn that into a load from the pool for you.

For what you want to do I think the pc relative add (adr) is the best you are going to get.  You can try other toolchains as all of this is language and toolchain specific (assembly language is defined by the assembler not the target and for each toolchain (with an assembler) there can be differences in the language).  Over time within gnu, how the linker and assembler worked together has changed, the linker patches up things it didn't used to.

You could of course go into the linker and add code to it to perform this optimization, the problem is most likely that by link time the linker is looking to resolve an address in the pool which is easy for it to do it doesn't have to change the instruction, the assembler would have to leave information for the linker that this is not just a fill this memory location with an address thing, either you modify gas to allow adr to work, and then if the linker cant resolve it within the instruction then the linker bails out with an error.'

Or you could just hard-code what you want and maintain it. I am not sure why the adr solution isn't adequate.

`mov r0,#8` is a valid thumb instruction.

Comment: note the answer was in the previous post's answer, so this is technically a duplicate.

Comment: I think that I got what is the problem, I will try it tomorrow and I will send the updates :) Thanks a lot for your answer anyway!

Comment: You are correct, I got confused because the adr command was not in the ARMV5 manual and I "not so cleverly" thought that it is not supported by ARMV5. And then you said that and I realized that is a pseudo  instruction and the assembler will convert it to something supported by the architecture. Thanks a lot for your time, I know that it seems a bit of a silly question but it helped me to get a better intuition on the subject.

Comment: when in doubt just try it worst case the assembler doesnt recognize it...thats what I did, got lucky I guess.