# How to load multiple data directly from label to registers

Tags: assembly, arm

I wanted to know if there was a way to load, say an array of words stored in memory, into an array of registers.

I know ldm can be used to load many registers at once, but my understanding is that you need to provide it with a register that already holds the first element.

Is there some pseudo-instruction that can help? Something like ldm =array, {r0,r1,r2} (fashioned after the actual pseudo-instruction ldr).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On recent ARM there's `ldp` that loads a pair of registers.  Not sure if `ldm` is possible with a nearby PC-relative addressing mode.  If the data is farther away you need the label address in a register anyway.  You could just use the last register to be loaded as the scratch reg for the address.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I think that the `ldm` will load the source to an internal load/store pipe register so clobbering it with a load inside the target list is ok.  The issue is with write back.  It is a bit non-sensical to load the register from memory **AND** write back the end value.  But the OP doesn't want this.  I wouldn't be surprised if some ARM somewhere didn't support `ldm rN, {...,rN}` but it is suppose to work.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Yeah, I was picturing using `ldm` *without* write-back for overwriting the address register.  If that's possible. (And since I mentioned the possibility in my first comment, PC-relative `ldm` is not possible.  Instead of a displacement, the instruction uses that space in the instruction word for the bitmap of which registers to load.  Thanks for the reminder that ldm needs a pointer in a register, not a normal addr mode.)

Answer (score 1):

See: [Getting a label to a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm)

There are four ways to get a label in traditional ARM,

```
 target:
     .long 0xfeadbeef, 0xdeadfeed, 0xbaddad00
```

1. `adr r0,target`
2. `adrl r0,target`
3. `ldr   r0,=target`
4. `sub   r0,pc,#(.+8-target)`

*Thumb2 adds the `movw` `movt` combo, but that doesn't work for your use case.*

Item 1,2,4 are basically the same.  The item 3 adds an address as a constant to the *literal pool* and this address is loaded to the register.  Something in 'C' like.

```
int variable;
const int *p = &variable;
int *reg = p; /* load register from memory */
```

> Is there some pseudo-instruction that can help? Something like ldm =array, {r0,r1,r2} (fashioned after the actual pseudo-instruction ldr).

**There are no pseudo-op for this; you must directly code things.**

Given the 'target' definition above with three values, you can do this with...

```
 target:
     .long 0xfeadbeef, 0xdeadfeed, 0xbaddad00
 adr  r0, target
 ldm  r0, {r0-r2}  ; r0 as source/dest should work without write back
                   ; ldm r0, {r1-r3} maybe safer.
```

The pseudo-ops **aren't** implemented as this is 'rare' and the `ldm` is restrictive and doesn't support offsets of PC as a source.  Something like,

```
 ; I just thunk it.
 ldm pc, {r0-r2,pc}  ; pc is always '8' ahead, assuming arm mode.
 nop
 .long arg0, arg1, arg2, routine
```

maybe possible but is restrictive as the data has to be positioned with the code and the control flow is also restrictive.  Again this is a rare use case and the pseudo-op is to make it much easier to get arbitrary constants into registers which is commonly needed.  So there are only direct coding of `ldm` commands.  It is possible that some ARM CPU/architechure doesn't support having the same register as a destination; definitely not supported with write back (rN!).  It depends on the class of ARM CPUs you are targeting.  Using the `PC` as the source is probably even more unlikely to work over a large class of ARM CPUs.  I would recommend the first example (rN != r15) unless you are running out of registers and on a known SOC/specific ARM CPU.

---

The `ldrd` instruction is a restrictive double word load but the source has more flexibility.  You can use it to load two values without needing a separate `adr`.  For example,

```
ldr r0, r1, [pc, #offset]
```

But it is limited to two registers.  The target register need to be consecutive and  the first is rN where `N % 2` is zero or **N is even**.

Comment: `ldm` isn't really a pseudo-op, it's a real machine instruction.  Unless you mean in the sense of being [an alias for `ldmia`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABCAEDD.html).  The manual does say write-back is optional, but also says "**Rn must not be PC**".  (At least on Cortex-M3, which is what google turned up for `ldm ldmia`).  But also that *reglist must not contain Rn if you specify the writeback suffix.* which is makes it explicit by implication that *without* write-back you can safely overwrite the address register.  (Again, docs for Cortex-M3)