# Can't load a word into register

Tags: assembly, arm

Being a newbie in Assembly language I managed to tripped up over this hello-world-like program:

```
.global _start
_start:
    ldr R0, =val
    mov R7, #1
    svc 0
.data
    val: .word 0xffffffff
```

My intent is just to load the `val` word into `R0`, so its value would be used as the program's exit status (its the least significant byte, to be precise). However, instead of the expected value, `ff_16 = 255`, I get such an output from bash:

```
$ ./prog; echo $?
132
```

Output of disassemblying:

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e59f0004        ldr     r0, [pc, #4]    ; c <_start+0xc>
   4:   e3a07001        mov     r7, #1
   8:   ef000000        svc     0x00000000
   c:   00000000        .word   0x00000000
```

It shows the presence of an offset from `PC` by `4` but the word marked as `4:` is not the desired one, is it? On the other hand, even this word does not contain `84_16 = 132` value, so where it springs from?

Some clarification is needed, please.

Architecture: arm7l, OS: raspberrypi 5.4.72-v7+

Comment: As noted, you have one level of indirection too many.  But note that you can get the desired behavior more simply by just doing `ldr R0, =#0xffffffff`, and the compiler will put the value in the literal pool for you, saving you the trouble of defining a `val` for yourself.  In fact, `0xffffffff` aka `-1` does not need a memory load at all, as this value can be encoded into an immediate: just do `mov R0, #0xffffffff`.  Smaller and faster.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you for this complement!

Comment: Combine with [Getting label to address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm), the cited duplicate and this question should answer your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction

```
        ldr r0, =val
```

loads the address of `val` into `R0`.  It assembles to something like

```
        ldr r0, foo
        ...
foo:    .int val
```

To load the value of `val`, you need

```
        ldr r0, val
```

Note that this only works if `val` is reasonably close by (e.g. closer than about ±1 kB).  If `val` is far away or in another segment (as is in your case), you'll need to first load the address and then the datum:

```
        ldr r0, =val
        ldr r0, [r0]
```

Also note that you might want to use a `movw`/`movt` pair instead of the `ldr r0, =...` instruction if supported (ARMv7 has it); it's slightly faster where supported as it eliminates a load:

```
        movw r0, :lower16:val
        movt r0, :upper16:val
```

These two instructions can be issued interspersed with other instructions, but if they are given consecutively, they macro fuse on some cores which gives a performance benefit, so try to do that.  You can also use a lone `movw` to load any 16 bit value into a register.

Comment: Oh, I got it that `ldr` just loaded the *address*, not the value. But still, could you clarify why is there `#4` in the `ldr r0, [pc, #4]` dissasembly line? `PC` + four bytes is the address of the `mov` command, not one of the needed word `val`, isn't it?

Comment: @IlyaLoskutov Recall that the program counter runs ahead of the current instruction by 8 bytes during execution.  The address this resolves to is `0xc` as given in the comment on the right.