# Cortex M-4 Arm processor mov / movt / movw

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I was hoping to get some clarification on something that I’m having trouble understanding.

I am using cortex-m processor with gnu assembler and I’m trying to put 0x1A2B3F4C into r0.

In the book that I’m reading it says that MOV only takes an 8 bit value constant, immediate value.

I tried playing around with it with my board in the IDE and I saw that doing both mov r0,#0x3F4C movt r0,#0x1A2B and movw r0,#0x3F4C movt r0,#0x1A2B work.

Why is that? I don't understand why mov works because 0x3F4C isn't an 8 bit number, unless my understanding of it is really wrong.

I appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

I was expecting mov to not work because it’s not an 8 bit value.

Comment: Consult a disassembly. Probably your assembler turned the `MOV` into `MOVW` or equivalent sequence of instructions for your convenience.

Comment: Your assembler helpfully turns `mov r0, #0x3f4c` into `movw r0, #0x3f4c`.

Comment: There is also [a good ARM blog on constants](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture).  Mainly, it has another detail you might like to know of how to create and address from a label. `#:lower16:label, #:upper16:label` and [Label address to a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm).

Comment: what part of the arm documentation do you not understand?

Comment: cortex m is not goverend by the 8 bit rule that is full sized arm.   cortex-m has its own set of rules

Comment: and the arm rule is also dependent on architecture and is not strictly 8 bits...

Comment: but is all documented in the architecture manuals and cortex-m is different architectures so you need to specify which architecture/core you are running cortex-m is not sufficient.

Comment: To paraphrase old timer.  *the book that I’m reading* was probably authored for an older version of the ARM architecture.  There are various versions of ARM and the Cortex-M is a version of 'ARMv7' for micro-controllers.  So, you need to be careful that the information you read matches the technology you are using.

Comment: Thank you guys! I emailed the author of the book and he clarified everything. Thank you so much for the help