# adr/adrp for arm architecture (J.R. Gibson book)

Tags: arm

at page 155 of 2nd editon of "ARM Assembly Language - an Introduction" by J.R. Gibson we've got a sentence:

Using the pseudo instruction ADR xyz the assembler determines the amount to add to the present value of the program counter and relpaces ADR with either:
ADD Rn, pc, #value, 4
or
SUB Rn, pc, #value, 4

Ok, suppose the #value is an even (divisible by 4) offset.
But why to rotate #value by 4 bits *right* (#value, 4 means ROR 4 bits I presume)?

Event if pipeline effects considered, the #value should already account for that (pc at the moment of the instruction execution is +8 bytes ahead).

I feel I don't understand something fundamentally simple in
ADD Rn, pc, #value, 4

SUB Rn, pc, #value, 4

examples.

Comment: No, the 4 doesn't mean `ror #4`. It's quite misleading to put a 4 at the end IMO.

Comment: So what does it stand for?..

I mean, the instruction:

mov r4, #182, 12

means "mov to r4 value of 182 (dec), rotated 12 times (bits) right".

Instruction

add r4, r5, #4080

is equivalent to add r4, r5, #255, 28

Comment: That's one operand too many.

Comment: add r4, r5, #255, 28 -- is ok.

Comment: A question is: does it have any special semantics, when 'pc' is the destination register.

Comment: The ARM assembler takes care of shifting constants.  You just list the constant.  The only time to specify shift involves registers.  Consider the facts, 1. The author may be wrong.  2. The author is referring to a different assembler (or even ISA); especially relevant for old books [2nd edition is 2011] vs new technology.  See also: [ARM assembler labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774581/getting-an-label-address-to-a-register-on-arm), which is basically what this pseudo-op is for. `adrp` is for pages.  `adrl` is more common.  Please specify the assembler?  `gas` or arm?

Comment: The technique of using a assembler stanza and then using disassembler can be helpful.  You don't need to believe either Jake or myself.  Trust your eyes.  Indeed the internet can be wrong, but so can books.

Comment: > Please specify the assembler? gas or arm

Arm. Precisely, Keil Arm.

And it's just an example from the book I don't understand.

All your points are valid, of course.

Comment: Keil is generally compatible, but the largest difference is in assembler.  I can not help you with very nuanced details of that assembler (as to why `add r4,r5,#255,28` is accepted; but the real question is does the 28 do anything or it is just discarded).  Some assemblers use # as a comment, so that might confound things.  Ie, `add r4,r5,r5,28` is bad, but not a #255.

Comment: Also, I see the topic is confusing.  For the assembler only register shift are specified. You are right in the op-code we have 8 bits with shifts to get a successful encoding.  However, you generally just give the constant to the assembler and it figures out the shift.  For case where the constant doesn't fit, there is `ldr rX,=#0xabcdef`, which is another pseudo-op.  Then, I think somehow the author gave this misleading extra stuff (not sure why?).  Perhaps there was an assembler that allowed a constant shift, but it is not normal in my experience.

Comment: Well, the question was "why adr xyz translates to ADD Rn, pc, #value, 4", presuming the "#value" is a valid offset (calculated by the assembler) from 'pc' value at the moment of execution to the address labeled "xyz". For me it would be ok without that ", 4" which really means "Rotate Right by 4 bits".